# using `angular.copy ` to set model - what's the benefit?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Today I was reviewing [this widget](https://github.com/jseppi/angular-dropdowns/blob/master/dist/angular-dropdowns.js) and found the following way [to set property](https://github.com/jseppi/angular-dropdowns/blob/master/dist/angular-dropdowns.js#L81):

```
if (selected !== $scope.dropdownModel) {
    angular.copy(selected, $scope.dropdownModel);
}
```

I'm wondering what's the benefit of such method as opposed to:

```
$scope.dropdownModel = selected;
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometime you want to have a copy of the original model lying around so that you can reset the element's model to the original value, for example, if you have a form and the user edits it, then decides to cancel the changes, how would you revert the forms input value to the original ones? You need a copy of the original model since the binding between the model and the form is 2 way, and all changes made to the form will affect the model, so you need a copy of the original model if you want to roll back the edit. Angular.copy basically removes the reference from the object and creates a separate copy.

Comment: thanks, but I don't where the code saves this model, can you please point me there?

Comment: `angular.copy(selected, $scope.dropdownModel);` is basically saying `$scope.dropdownModel=angular.copy(selected);` this copies the contecnts of selected into dropdownModel

Comment: yes, I understand that, I don't see where the `selected` object is saved for future reference